# Is HTML5 localstorage appropriate to store input field values?

Tags: html, forms, local-storage

I have a question, on how to best store local values of some form fields.

In my website, users use the keypad to keep a tally count of items. They can enter a label for the items they count. The problem is that each user apply different labels for their needs - and, each time they visit the labels are blank.

My sites are running through site44.com, which does not allow the use of server side php. So, in my [research](http://www.diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), I think using HTML5 localstorage may allow a user to keep the label after the exit the site?

Is this a correct interpretation?

Can someone give me a guide if I have, say 3 inputs - with different ids - how to set up the script?

Comment: so you want to save these inputs in the localstorage of the browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the local storage like this :

```
var fn = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
localStorage.setItem("firstname", fn);

var ln = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
localStorage.setItem("lastname", ln);

var em = document.getElementById("email").value;
localStorage.setItem("email", em);
```

thus the clients browser will have these items set in their local storage.
Now if a user visits the website afterwards. you can check for the value of localStorage and find the items of your need.

Suppose on users' next visit you want to send him a greet message ( he has not logged in ofcourse ) you can use a script like this below:

```
var name = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
alert("Hello"+name);
```

Comment: Okay, I'll take your idea and see if it can serve my purpose. I'll vote your idea if it works or maybe clarify any issues I have. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: On implementation, if I check for the presence of these localstorage variables, do I need to `getitem` to re-populate the input fields with the user labels?

Comment: ofcourse, you need to do getItem to get the value of the key you have stored in the local storage. And ,one more thing, check for this this localstorage only for the site for which you have saved it.

Comment: thanks, this ended up working like a charm. thanks for the advice.